# Determine if an ideal is principal, Structure of Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I = (9,7 + \sqrt{-5}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-5}]$ and $J = (3,1 + \sqrt{-5}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-5}]$.

First, I have to show that $I =J^{2}$. I got that $J^{2} = (9,3+3\sqrt{-5},-4+2\sqrt{-5})$. I can clearly see that $I\subseteq J^2$ because $3+3\sqrt{-5} + -(-4+2\sqrt{-5}) = 7 +\sqrt{-5}$, but I can't see the other direction.

Second, I have to determine if $(9, 7 + \sqrt{-5})$ is principal. I know that the norm of a potential generator must divide $81,54$ the norms of the individual elements of the ideal. So the possibilities are norm $1,3,9,27$, but I do not know how to proceed. I was wondering if there a gcd method in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ similar to $\mathbb{Z}$ for checking if an ideal is principal.

Third, I have to determine the invariant factors of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/I$ as an abelian group. I don't know how to do this. In the last step, I got that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/I \cong \mathbb{Z}_{9}$ (may not be true) which would imply invariant factors of $1,9$.

Lastly, I have to determine if $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/I$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/J$ are fields. For this I used the following logic $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/(9,7 + \sqrt{-5}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x] / (9,7+x,x^{2}+5) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{9}[x] / (7+x,x^{2}+5) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{9}[x] / (1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{9}$. Using a similar approach I got that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Thus, I made the determination that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J$ is a field and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is not a field. Is this argument correct? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Partial hints*:

For the reverse inclusion $J^\subset I$, you have
\begin{align}
3+3\sqrt{-5}&=3(7+\sqrt{-5})-2\times 9, \\
-4+2\sqrt{-5}&=23(7+\sqrt{-5})-2\times 9.
\end{align}

A gcd method doesn't exist, for it would imply that $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ (which is a Dedekind ring) is principal, which it is not. You have to compute the norm of this ideal and check whether there exists an element with that norm.

Comment: Are $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] / I \cong \mathbb{Z}_{9}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] / J \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ correct statements?

Comment: I think so, since $x^2+5$ has roots modulo $9$ as well as modulo $3$.